# Method Call Shifts Parameter

Tags: java, android

I want to read a HashMap value from a string entered in an AutocompleteTextView. This is how the string is retrieved:

```
  EditText phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
  String phoneNum = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
```

I then send the string to a lookup function:

```
GetPhoneFromName(phoneNum);
```

I enter the function using the debugger. If the original value of the parameter is "שער", when I enter the function it appears as "קנצ" which is the same word, but with each letter transposed by subtracting 1 from the ASCII value. Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Does it do it with "regular text"? Could be an encoding problem. And you're *sure* the text is what you think it is prior to passing to the lookup?

Comment: it happens only in the debugger ? does the edittext shows something diffrent ?

Comment: Tried with an English string, and the parameter was not corrupted, so it seems likely that this does have to do with encoding, but how and why?

Comment: @AharonManne No idea. Look at the documentation for the EditText and see if it expects a certain encoding, or lets you pick the encoding.